# Bouncing a body from the walls of another body. Phaser3

Tags: phaser-framework

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: '#1b1464',
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter: {
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('red', 'assets/sprites/columns-red.png');
}

function create ()
{
    this.matter.world.setBounds(100, 0, 600, 400, 1).disableGravity();
    console.log(this.matter.world.walls.bottom)

    var circ = this.matter.add.image(200, 50, 'red');

    //  Change the body to a Circle with a radius of 48px
    circ.setBody({
        type: 'circle',
        radius: 48
    });

    //  Just make the body move around and bounce
    circ.setVelocity(6, 3);
    circ.setAngularVelocity(0.01);
    circ.setBounce(1);
    circ.setFriction(1, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.19.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.19.0/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**There is a code according to which the ball is squared and bounces off its walls. How can I rotate this square?**

I am ready to accept proposals for the implementation of this example on other phaser engines

Comment: it's not clear for me what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to have the same effect without using the matter physics? Could you provide an edit & include a more detail explanation?

Comment: @Manuel Abascal, I need to make the ball bounce off the walls inside the rotating square. It makes no difference to me what engine it will be on. The main thing is that it is on the phaser. How to do it?

Comment: do you wish to rotate the square bound borders?

Comment: @Manuel Abascal, yes, but I want the ball to bounce from it